# How to find the user input time lies between which two time frame stored in array in bash script

Tags: linux, shell-script, time, bash-array

let the given array is `array=(12:45 01:30 02:02 02:55 03:55)`
so how to find the time let, `12:50` is lie between which two time frame(with index) is bash script

```bash
array=(12:45 01:30 02:02 02:55 03:55)
read -p "enter time(HH:MM):" time
```

If I enter `12:50` the output should be:

```
the time 12:50 lies in between 12:45 and 1:30

first_index:0    #(first_index means index of 12:50) 

last_index:1     #(last_index means index of 01:30)
```

Comment: You‘ll need to iterate through the array for this.

Comment: You should consider **24 Hour Time Format**. For example, when comparing `12:45` and  `01:30` should be `00:45` and `01:30` or `12:45` and `13:30`. This makes the `if` comparisons easier.

Comment: Don't you have problem if you change your times to **24 Hour Time Format**?  And what about to input a value that exists in your array? What should be the output?